# How to generate and filter efficiently all combinations of a list of list product

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello guys here is the problem. I have something like this in input [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]...etc

And i want to generate all possible combination of product of those list and then multiply each elements of the resulting combination beetween them to finally filter the result in a interval.

So first input a n list [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]...etc

Which will then give (1,4,7,10)
                     (1,4,7,11)
                     (1,4,7,12) 
and so on

Then combination of those result for k in n like (1,4,7)(1,4,10)(1,7,10) for the first row

The multiplication of x as 1*4*7 = 28, 1*4*10 = 40, 1*7*10 = 70

And from this get only the unique combination and the result need in the interval choosed beforehand : if x > 50 and x < 100 i will get (1,7,10) : 70

I did try

```
    def mult(lst):                 #A function mult i'm using later
        r = 1
        for element in lst:
           r *= element
        return round(r)

    s = []                                #Where i add my list of list
    for i in range(int(input1)):
        b = input("This is line %s : " % (i+1)).split()
        for i in range(len(b)):
           b[i] = float(b[i]) 
        s.append(b)

    low_result = input("Expected low_result : ")
    high_result = input("Expected high_result : ")

    combine = []
    my_list = []

    for element in itertools.product(*s):
       l= [float(x) for x in element]
       comb = itertools.combinations([*l], int(input2))
       for i in list(comb):
          combine.append(i)
          res = mult(i)
          if res >= int(low_result) and res <= int(high_result):
             my_list.append(res) 
             f = open("list_result.txt","a+")
             f.write("%s : result is  %s\n" % (i, res))
             f.close()
```

And it always result in memory error cause there is too many variation with what i'm seeking.

What i would like is a way to generate from a list of list of 20 elements or more all the product and resulting combination of k in n for the result(interval) that i need.

Comment: If you are looking for the AXBXCX... 
And then trying to take a subset dim = n-1 , might as well start with choosing (n-1) spaces? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Try to replace the lists by generators, replace [] by () they will save you some memory

Comment: Also [*l] is the same as l if l is a list

Comment: And I think numpy will help you with some performance. But I'm not the Python numbers guy

Comment: If i replace [] by () it won't do with the combination because it will give it too much argument no ?

Comment: BorntbeWasted sorry i don't see what you make allusion to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above, I think this can be done without exploding your memory by never holding an array in memory at any time. But the main issue is then runtime.

**The maths**

As written we are:

- Producing every combination of `m` rows of `n` items `n ** m`
- Then taking a choice of `c` items from those `m` values `C(m, c)`

This is very large. If we have `m=25` rows, of `n=3` items each and pick `c=3` items in them we get:

- `= n ** m * C(m, c)`
- `= 3 ** 25 * 2300` - [n Choose r calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php)
- `= 1.948763802×10¹⁵`

If instead we:

- Choose `c` rows from the `m` rows: `C(m, c)` as before
- Then pick every combination of `n` items from these `c` rows: `n ** c`

With `m=25` rows, of `n=3` items each and pick `c=3` items in them we get:

- = `n ** c * C(m, c)`
- = `3 ** 3 * 2300`
- = `20700`

This is now a solvable problem.

**The code**

```
from itertools import product, combinations


def mult(values, min_value, max_value):
    """
    Multiply together the values, but return None if we get too big or too
    small
    """
    output = 1

    for value in values:
        output *= value

        # Early return if we go too big
        if output > max_value:
            return None

        # Early return if we goto zero (from which we never return)
        if output == 0 and min_value != 0:
            return None

    if output < min_value:
        return None

    return output


def yield_valid_combos(values, choose, min_value, max_value):
    # No doubt an even fancier list compression would get this too
    for rows in combinations(values, choose):
        for combos in product(*rows):
            value = mult(combos, min_value, max_value)

            if value is not None:
                yield combos, value


values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]


with open('list_result.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for selection, value in yield_valid_combos(
            values, choose=3, min_value=50, max_value=100):
        fh.write('{}: result is {}\n'.format(selection, value))
```

This solution also returns no duplicate answers (unless the same value appears in multiple rows).

As an optimisation the multiplication method attempts to return early if we detect the result will be too big or small. We also only open the file once and then keep adding rows to it as they come.

**Further optimisation**

You can also optimise your set of values ahead of time by screening out values which cannot contribute to a solution. But for smaller values of `c`, you may find this is not even necessary.

The smallest possible combination of values is `c` items from the set of the smallest values in each row. If we take the `c - 1` smallest items from the set of smallest values, mutliply them together and then divide the maximum by this number, it gives us an upper bound for the largest value which can be in a solution. We can then then screen out all values above this value (cutting down on permutations)

Comment: Sadly the values does not lokk like these more like [[1.16,6.3,12],[1.27,5.5,9],[2.42,3.3,2.85],[1.3,5.4,9.5],[2.78,3.35,2.32],[2.45,2,1.88]] up to maybe 25 element or more. That's why i'm really curious about the way you present at the end of your answer cause the time need for treating all those combination look near infinite no ?

Comment: It's possible to generalise the logic above for arbitrary values. If we collect the set of the smallest values from each set, we can create an upper bound for the largest value that can be a part of our solution by: removing the largest value from this set, multiplying the rest together, dividing our maximum by that value. We can then remove values from sets which are above this value. This will speed up the process as it cuts on permutations, but if we find any particular set is empty, we also know there is no solution before we start.

Comment: Ahh... sorry it's actually take the `choose - 1` smallest values from the set of smallest values, then divide the max by that.

Comment: I think I've cracked it, the product and the choice should be the other way around... I'll update the answer.